# Techniques to check if relationship exists in Doctrine2

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I can't seem to find any mention in the Doctrine documentation on how to check if an entity has an existing relationship to another entity:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-associations.html

In Doctrine 1.x there was a method called `exists` that could be called on an entity to check this:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/working-with-models#dealing-with-relations:clearing-related-records

In Doctrine 2.0 this is what I've tended to do. What techniques are other people using?

```
<?php

class Group    {
    private $id;
    protected $name;
    protected $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->colorgroups = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function hasUsers() {
        return count($this->users) > 0;
    } 
}
```

Comment: +1 for the allusive profile name :)

Comment: Love that comment from someone who chose to go by @Bastardo -.-

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well - I actually stumbled on the correct answer today while looking though the ArrayCollection class. You should use the 'isEmpty' method.

From the code (the comments are theirs, not mine)

```
/**
 * Checks whether the collection is empty.
 * 
 * Note: This is preferrable over count() == 0.
 *
 * @return boolean TRUE if the collection is empty, FALSE otherwise.
 */
public function isEmpty()
{
    return ! $this->_elements;
}
```

So from my example

```
public function hasUsers() {
        return !$this->users->isEmpty();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Doctrine2 uses different architecture than Doctrine1.2. If you want to check whether a group has a certain user associated with it you should write a method `hasUser(User $user)` that will determine it:

```
public function hasUser(User $user) {
    foreach ($this->users as $u) {
        if ($u->equals($user)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

If you want to check whether a relationship is persisted in database you will have to execute a the following DQL query:

```
SELECT 1 FROM MyProject\Entity\Group g WHERE :user MEMBER OF g.users;
```

Where `:user` is `User` object.

Comment: This seems alot more verbose than my own method (1 line vs 6 lines). Does your method offer any advantage over mine? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Super pedantic but HQL != DQL

Comment: Ops... I did it out of habit. ;) Fixed. About the advantage... there is none. There is no shorter solution to check if an object belongs to the collection (optionally you could use [ArrayCollection::contains()](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.0/doctrine/common/collections/arraycollection.html#contains()) which actually do quite similar thing). Your `hasUsers()` do something else and should be included right before my method in real world application by the way.

Comment: Well - this question died a death - I was interested in seeing different approaches but the truth is that is probably not complicated enough to warrant more than one approach :-) Marked as correct

Comment: Crozin's approach is different as it has the ability to check whether a relationship exists in a *preexisting* collection whereas kissmyface's only checks whether the collection exists or not. I am trying to implement your approach Crozin but I am getting an error sayings `equals()` is an undefined method which is not so surprising given I can't find any mention of it anywhere in the documentation. Would you care to elaborate on your answer Crozin?

Comment: It's just a simple, user-defined method in the `User` class that returns `true` if object given in its first argument is equal to the current (`this`) object. It's a direct equivalent of Java's `equals()` method.

Comment: @Crozin Is this still the best way to check whether or not an object association exists in your opinon?

Comment: @Jimbo You could use [`ArrayCollection::contains()` function](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.1/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html), just keep in mind that for objects it uses reference equality which might or might not be acceptable for you.

Comment: Should 2nd line be; foreach ($this->users as $u)

Comment: @srayner Yes, it should be. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You can use Exists method http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.4/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html#_exists something like this

```
$someId = 123;
$p = function($key, $element) use ($someId){
     return $element->getId() == $someId;
};

$u->exists($p); //here is your result
```

Comment: Nice - though you'd need to be careful about your memory consumption about using closures inside entities. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php#70691

Comment: no, you'd need to be careful about your memory :D you said "I was interested in seeing different approaches" so this i one... in my option this sollution is best i think SELECT 1 FROM MyProject\Entity\Group g WHERE :user MEMBER OF g.users;

Comment: I appreciate the input - it's always nice to see other alternatives. You also encouraged me to check out the query class more thoroughly which includes all sorts of things that are useful but not fully documented. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use Exception handling

```
try {

$entity = $entity->getAnotherEntity() ; // OneToOne Mapping 

}catch(\Exception $e) {

$entity = null ;

}
```

P.S More specific exception  can be used to make it even better .

Comment: Are you sure, that O-O mapping in Doctrine would throw an exception if there is no linked Entity? Suppose, that there would be null.

Answer (score -2):

I know this is an old question, but it could be useful to someone else or maybe even to you.
I think what you were looking for was the `relatedExists()` method that you can find here:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/working-with-models.html#clearing-related-records

Hope it will be useful!

Comment: The relatedExists function is for Doctrine1, this question was for Doctrine2.