# Doctrine2 Check if related entity exists

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm really tired to figuring out how I can check in Doctrine 2 if related entity record exists in DB. Help me please.

For example I have two entities. One is the order status of certain delivery company. Another one is order.

**Order.php**

```php
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Application\DeliveryBundle\Entity\DpdOrderStatus", mappedBy="order")
 * @var DpdOrderStatus
 */
$dpdOrderStatus;
```

**DpdOrderStatus.php**

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\Application\FrontendBundle\Entity\Order", inversedBy="dpdOrderStatus")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
 * @var Order
 */
$order;
```

Order entity sometimes doesn't have status and I need to check if it has.

AFAIK if I will try to use `is_null($order->getDpdOrderStatus())` it will always be `false` because Doctrine always create `Proxy` objects for its entities if `EAGER` mode is not specified.

So what is the most proper way to check if my status entity exists in database?

Comment: Have you tried that? Doctrine's proxy will load the missing data.

Comment: Sorry, that's my mistake. I mean false of course.

Answer (score 1):

Add a method that checks if the order has an order status:

**Order.php**

```
public function hasOrderStatus(){
 return ! is_null($this->dpdOrderStatus);
}
```

More information: [Techniques to check if relationship exists in Doctrine2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224848/techniques-to-check-if-relationship-exists-in-doctrine)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
public function hasOrderStatus() {
    return !is_null($this->dpdOrderStatus) && (bool) $this->dpdOrderStatus->getId();
}
```